# Create client under CSP using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

We are switching from reseller/advisor accounts to CSP.

We can manually create Customers under PartnerCenter which creates the relationship as Cloud Reseller as opposed to Advisor as before.
We can create the company name fine and add License based subscriptions however when we add Usage Based Subscription it lists the subscription name as Microsoft Azure instead of our Company Name. Also we have to go into this subscription and manually create AzureReader and AzureAdmin users under the ARM Portal.

I am looking for powershell options to automate this process:

1. Create a new client under CSP using powershell.
2. Create a usage based subscription with our Company Name instead of Subscription name of Microsoft Azure under this new client.
3. Add the AzureReader and AzureAdmin users to the Subscription.

Any assistance is appreciated.

I looked through several forums as well as scripts on Github but have not found anything and unfortunately I am not a coder or powershell guru.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer -

Powershell preview is out now [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PartnerCenterPowerShellModule)

<strike>i am afraid there are no power-shell to accomplish this but instead there is a .net sdk or a REST API that can help to accomplish this.</strike>

Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/mt634668.aspx)